# width.find ('.') works for the first scenario but does not work the second scenario despite using same code

Tags: c++, string

Sorry if my naming conventions make this a bit confusing.

I'm trying to turn a string into both an `int` and a `double`. It works for one string but not the other.

```cpp
stringstream widths (width);
if (width.find ('.') == true) {            //IF THERE IS DECIMAL CONVERT WIDTH STRING TO WIDTH DOUBLE
    widths >> wd;
}
else {
    widths >> wi;                          //IF THERE IS NO DECIMAL CONVERT WIDTH STRING TO WIDTH INTEGER
}

stringstream lengths (length);              //DITTO
cout << length;                             //string displays decimals
if (length.find ('.') == true) {            //however this time it does not find it
    lengths >> ld;
    cout << endl << "DECIMAL DETECTED" << ld;
}
else {
    lengths >> li;
    cout << endl << "DECIMAL NOT DETECTED" << li;
}
```

It works for `width`, but when I do it for `length` it does not keep the numbers after the decimal.

Example Input:

```
5.468 132.22
```

Output:

```
5.468 132
```

`width` is `"5.468"` and `length` is `"132.22"`.

`wd` and `wi` return as `5.468`, however `ld` and `li` return as `132`.

I'm relatively new to coding, and I've been stuck trying to understand why this isn't working for a while.

Extra Context:

```cpp
int wi;       //WIDTH INTEGER LENGTH INTEGER
int li;
double wd;    //WIDTH DOUBLE LENGTH DOUBLE
double ld;
double area;     

int main() {
    string widthlength;    //STRING WIDTHLENGTH 
    string width;        //SUBSTRING WIDTH
    string length;       //SUBSTRING LENGTH
    getline (cin, widthlength);    //GET WIDTHLENGTH
    size_t space = widthlength.rfind (' ');  //FIND SPACE
    width = widthlength.substr(0, space);   //GET FIRST NUMBEER AS WIDTH
    length = widthlength.substr (space+1);   //GET SECOND NUMBER AS LENGTH
```

Comment: What in the world is this... There are functions built in the standard libraries such as std::stoi, std::stod, ::atoi, ::atof, etc.... look into those.

Comment: You may also want to remove the *Javascript* snippets from your question, since this is not javascript.

Comment: Hint: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) does not return a `bool`

Comment: Why do you think you should validate against `== true`??  See the Return in [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: haha appreciate the tips! sorry for making you all witness this horrid piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns an *index* to the found character, or `std::string::npos` if not found. It DOES NOT return a boolean indicating whether the character exists or not.

```cpp
stringstream widths (width);
if (width.find ('.') != string::npos) {
    widths >> wd;
}
else {
    widths >> wi;
}

stringstream lengths (length);
if (length.find ('.') != string::npos) {
    lengths >> ld;
    cout << endl << "DECIMAL DETECTED" << ld;
}
else {
    lengths >> li;
    cout << endl << "DECIMAL NOT DETECTED" << li;
}
```

Which you actually *already knew*, since you are using [`std::string::rfind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) in your `main()` using the return value as an *index*:

```cpp
size_t space = widthlength.rfind (' ');  //FIND SPACE
width = widthlength.substr(0, space);   //GET FIRST NUMBEER AS WIDTH
length = widthlength.substr (space+1);   //GET SECOND NUMBER AS LENGTH
```

The only difference between `find()` and `rfind()` is the direction in which they search - `find()` searches from front to back, `rfind()` searches from back to front.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve the issue just by removing the bool.

Comment: You might also consider getting rid of `rfind()` and `substr()` altogether and just use `std::istringstream` with `operator>>`, which handles the whitespace parsing for you.  And then consider reading the numbers into `double` variables unconditionally, which can hold integral values. You can use `std::modf()` if you need to know whether fractional decimals are present.